# PostgreSQL single-column table to JSON array

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT floor FROM rooms WHERE building_id = 23;
```

I want to convert the result into a JSON array. I was able to use `json_agg()` as follows:

```
SELECT json_agg(a) from (SELECT DISTINCT floor FROM rooms WHERE building_id = 23) as a;
```

But that results in an array of key/value pairs:

```
[{"floor":null},{"floor":1},{"floor":4},{"floor":2},{"floor":0},{"floor":3}]
```

When really I want an array of just the values:

```
[null,1,4,2,0,3]
```

For performance and bandwidth reasons, I don't want to have the column name repeated unnecessarily. Any ideas on how to make a JSON array of just the values?

(I also tried `array_to_json(array_agg())`, but that produced the same results as `json_agg()`)

Comment: Why not convert the data structure to json in whatever language you are using to do the query?

Comment: Why not just concatanate the values?

Comment: @MattKoskela I could, but building the JSON in Postgres is (potentially) much faster. Postgres's implementation of JSON encoding is probably faster than the library I can use in my application, and by doing it all in Postgres there aren't any extraneous intermediate formats. Rather than Table -> ODBC? -> Psycopg2 -> Python data structures -> JSON, it gets turned into JSON before it even leaves Postgres, and it's just a string from then on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `a` in `json_agg(a)` is a table alias.  If you encode that into JSON, you'll get a dictionary with column name / column value pairs.  Refer to the column name instead:

```
select  json_agg(floor)
from    (
        select  distinct floor
        from    rooms 
        where   building_id = 23
        ) a
```

Or even simpler, use `json_agg(distinct ...)` instead of a subquery:

```
select  json_agg(distinct floor)
from    rooms
where   building_id = 23
```